# vs code terminal result different from locale terminal

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I am trying to run a python code using VS code, I noticed that the result is different from the local terminal.
here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'

a=tf.constant(10)
print(f"a = {a}")
```

its successfully running using my local terminal and I am having the error below while using my vs code terminal.

````
File "00-test.py", line 11
    print(f"a = {a}")
                   ^```
````

Comment: Are both cases run using the same Python version? Also please provide full error stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if the two pythons in vscode terminal and local terminal have the same version,or with the same enviro